# Select rows from data frame based on condition and apply function

Tags: pandas

I have following example of data frame

```
  Marked       City
1   0        New York
2   1         California
```

I want to select rows from data frame, where Marked is 0 and apply some function to City row. The data frame is big (more than 1M row) and function to apply is complex, so the option to use condition statement to whole data frame is bad, since i still iterate whole 1M records. Selection of rows in data frame based on condition reduces the number rows to 300k and applying function to them is much faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `loc` access:

```
def some_func(x): return 1

mask = df.Marked == 0

df.loc[mask, 'new_col'] = df.loc[mask].apply(some_func, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried something like this and got TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed